# Is it possible to create a start up disk for 14.04 LTS via Windows 7? My Ubuntu o/s has crashed

Tags: boot

I have "messed up" my system and when I boot up I get a blank screen which asks for my keyring login password. When I enter the password the screen goes completely blank and nothing further happens. I can only get out by switching off my laptop.

Comment: You can burn a Live CD from any OS -- the real question is most likely whether that can let you solve your problem, short of installing fresh.

Comment: ... and if you need a startup USB, try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can

**[Download PowerIso](http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm)**

Run the program as administrator and click on the following:
[image]

A box will appear and here you can choose what image file to "burn" onto a USB drive. It'll make it bootable.

However another option is clicking Ctrl+Alt+F1
[image]
This will allow you to browse your system, all you have to do is login.

Goodluck!

Comment: Can I reinstall Ubuntu and will it sense that I already have an installed version(which has crashed)? Will this solve my problem?

Comment: If you reinstall the system, then it's good as new. If you choose to accept this as your answer, then please check it :P