# Installing from USB stick

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

I have an ASUS laptop 32 bit with a crashed version of XP which still runs in safe mode.

However, it has no CD drive, so I downloaded 14.04 on a USB stick and set the computer to read the USB first in the BIOS but it doesn't seem to see the USB drive.

Is there some way to just format the hard file and install?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566757/is-it-possible-to-create-a-start-up-disk-for-14-04-lts-via-windows-7-my-ubuntu/566762#566762)

Also before trying my answer out, change the Boot Mode in your BIOS to "CSM" or "Legacy" instead of "UEFI" and try again.

Comment: I don't remember Windows XP using UEFI...

Comment: Only if XP is 32-bit though!  >:)  https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/extensible_firmware_interface.mspx

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to tell your laptop to boot from the USB first (and not the hard drive), there might be a boot menu available, or a setting in your BIOS to change.

Or the USB may not have been created successfully. If you're stuck on old windows XP the [Universal USB Installer from pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) should still work, and it was very successful.

Or, your it's possible your old laptop is unable to boot from a USB... I think there were old ways to install linux without using a cd/usb, but they involved a box full of floppy disks... a working usb cd/dvd reader, or a bootable usb would be the easiest. WUBI used to install Ubuntu from "inside" old windows versions, but it wasn't perfect & is no longer supported.